What is grooved plywood siding called?
I've seen plywood that has slots in it that make the plywood look like siding.

What is the proper industry name for that kind of plywood? And what thickness is most common?
Location: Eastern Ontario.

It doesn't look like siding. It is siding.

Texture One Eleven (commonly expressed as T1-11) Originally trademarked by the Douglas Fir Plywood Association and later owned by the American Plywood Association - the trademark is presently expired evidently, but the name will still get what you are after.
It comes in many thicknesses and other finish details, such as rough or sanded surface.

It comes in plywood and OSB. I've used both. Same results.

LMGTFY: plywood siding --> Yes, it is called "Plywood Siding". For example, from Home Depot:

This example has the grooves every 8" and an overall thickness of 19/32", which looks (in a non-scientific survey) to be typical. I found "decorative" panels that are 11/32" thick.

I miss the 70s.  Rooms inside the house covered with nicer looking panels.

I grew up (chronologically at least) in a house with paneling. Very much a 70s thing.

Funny, but never in a million years would I have used that search term.

A local hardware store called it "Smart Board".
I googled "smart board" plywood and found some results for SmartSide and Smart Panel.
SmartSide 38 Series 8 in. Application as 4 ft. x 8 ft. Cedar Texture OC Panel Engineered Treated Wood Siding
